# Angular with spring mvc

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I want to make a simple web project using angular 4 and spring mvc. I am wondering that how can i integrate angular 4 with spring mvc that runs on a same server. Right now i running spring in localhost:8080 and angular in localhost:4200.

I did a lot research on it but cann't find any proper solution yet.

**Spring-Project Structure**

[image: Spring- Project Structure]

**Angular - Project Structure**

[image]

Is that possible to run angular and spring mvc project on a same server??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe best practice is to have two separate projects.  That said, here's how we've incorporated an angular project into our Spring MVC project.

1. Renamed `src` folder in our angular project to `ng-src`.
2. Copied the contents of the angular project, not the folder itself, into our Spring MVC project.  This added `e2e`, `node_modules`, and `ng-src` and several files to the root of our Spring MVC project.
3. Renamed `index.html` in `ng-src` to `index.jsp`
4. Edit a few things in `.angular-cli.json`

   ```
   "root": "ng-src",
   "outDir": "src/main/webapp/app",
   ```

   and

   ```
   "index": "index.jsp",
   ```
5. If `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/`, add a resource mapping to spring config
   In XML:

   ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/app/**" location = "/app/"/>
   ```

   Java Config:

   ```
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/**")
               .addResourceLocations("/app/")
   }
   ```
6. As we develop, we have a process running in the background building angular:

   ```
   ng build --bh "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/app/" --w
   ```

   The `--bh` sets the baseHref used in generating `index.jsp`.  `--w` tells angular-cli to watch the directory and build anytime things change.

Any changes made to the angular project are made under ng-src.  Angular-cli will see those changes and build the project.  Your angular project is built to `/your-context-path/app/`

Our IDE watches the project for changes on the filesystem.  Depending on your IDE, you may need to configure it to watch.  I know eclipse doesn't by default.

You'll need to refresh the page in your browser to see changes (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).